# Thymeleaf #strings.replace with regex and th:fragment

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have persisted entity with field text. Inside text I have part to replace. myEntity.text:

```
some text
twoImages[12_v13.PNG, 10_v6.PNG]
text text text
twoImages[12_v13.PNG, 10_v6.PNG]
<h1>And HTML</h1>
```

So in view I want to use something like th:utext. But with replaced images blocks with th:fragment (~15 lines per fragment).

Output should be like this:

```
some text
<img .. 12_v13.PNG />
<br />
<img .. 12_v13.PNG />
<additional html />
text text text
<img .. 12_v13.PNG />
<br />
<img .. 12_v13.PNG />
<additional html />
<h1>And HTML</h1>
```

How to realize this with Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1):

If the entire text of the field is a single string, you will have to parse it using regex matcher or some generated parser. Say [12_v13.PNG, 10_v6.PNG] has to be parsed e.g. with 
    \\[([^,]*),\\s*([^\\]]*)] 
The first group will give 12_v13.PNG, the second one - 10_v6.PNG.

You need to provide the path to each of the images in src property of img tag.
You can achieve the result this way:

```
<img th:src="@{/images/test.png}" />
```

It is implied, that /images folder is within webapp folder of your project.

```
<img th:src="@{/resources/images/Picture.png}" />
```

Output as:

```
<img src="/resources/image/Picture.png" />
```

When you hit http://localhost:8080/myapp/resources/images/Picture.png in you browser then you should be able to access the image for the above syntax to work.

This link is useful: [Standard URL Syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

Please have a look at my thymeleaf demo project: [demo project](https://github.com/dk2k/thymeleaf-test/tree/master/src/main/resources/templates) (the folder with templates will get opened) You'll find data on project structure and examples of thymeleaf templates.

Comment: Thanks! I'm more concerned with layers, I want for engine to do it (parsing). Path to img is other q. Despite the fact that such a task should be standard I think to do something like a custom tag. ?